# Is there a ways to Get real Ip or IPV6 Address using Chrome using JSP

Tags: javascript, geolocation, location, ip, ipv6

I have a question on the IP address.  I can get my IP address however it is not the Public or IPV6 that I need for IP Stack to render my location properly.  Furthermore, I have the below code and is pulling the IP address and can look it up however is the ISP or not with in the 30 miles of my location.    I have reached for something in JSP that will help by either making a call and reading it back with public but not getting anything worth using.  I really would like to find the IPV6

the IP I get is not the public or showing my location,  Thank you for your help in advance

Code:   (Very Simple)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <title>Getting Clients IP</title>
    <style>
    p, h1 {
        color: green;
    }
    </style>
  
    <script src=
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
     
      <script>
     

                
    $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org?format=json", function(data) {
         
        // Setting text of element P with id gfg
        $("#gfg").html(data.ip);
    })
    </script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Get Local IP Address</h1>
        <h3>Public IP Address of user is:</h3>
        <p id="gfg"></p>
 
    </center>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: Does your ISP actually assign IPv6 addressing to you?

Comment: What does "JSP" mean? Do you mean Java Server Pages?

Comment: JSP is Java Server Pages or can do this is Java Script.

Comment: How accurate of a location do you expect?  For me, the location I get from "whatismyip.com" is about 500km off.  30km sounds pretty good.

Comment: Why do you think your computer uses IPv6 to communicate with the Internet? What do you see when you open https://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: Ron, you question if O go to Google or IpStack for example it will return the IPV6 and the proper info but running this Page it is getting the Local IP when is showing 30 miles away.  If you would like to test and see for your self it is pretty simple using 
https://www.onlinejspcompiler.com/compileJSP and drop in the Code I have in the original post  and you will get something like 9.9.0.0.0 ip address then  https://www.iplocation.net/ and you can see the IPV6 is pulled up,

Comment: `9.9.0.0.0` is not an IP address.

Comment: That is showing the ISP details for the IP address     I need the client details we were able to pull it in C# but cannot figure out how to do it in JSP or KS to put on our server..

Comment: 9.9.0.0.0   I know it was an example.. Of the results did you run the test I asked and cann

Comment: An example for what? You're asking for IPv6, but `9.9.0.0.0` looks more like a IPv4 address, even though it's also not IPv4. I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Java
   Thank you for your help however you have moved past the question into and area that is not on course of even close as it may seem you are either trying to make waves or issues or not fa miler to the question it is related to JS code and not what your ISP provider does or does not.  Thank you for your time, but I was serious and asking for help not to get into an online dispute  Have a good day  Iwas a question on how to PUll details with code not ISP related  and the JS call which you did not know what JSP ment

Comment: I'm asking for clarification. That's all. I don't see the dispute. What is `9.9.0.0.0` an example for? I know what JSP knows. My comment was: _What does "JSP" mean? Do you mean Java Server Pages?_ I was asking about JSP because there was no JSP code in your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help be I was able to get the location using  the Chrome EXT JS code  have a great day and thank you

Comment: I was asking to do it in Either JSP or JS. I was using JS and seemed to get the IP however I was thinking maybe JSP would give me a better platform to get my accurate results. .  At the end the résumé was the longitude and latitude and was able to pull that with chrome ext   thank you again

Comment: You should mention that you're looking for a solution for a private website. This won't work for public websites. You can't expect of visitors of your website to install browser extensions.

Comment: That is correct this is not for a public , sorry was not clear you can ask, but most people will not accept the location but for our needs it is exact what we needed.   For public do you have any suggestions for future if I need to do Public?  Just curious

Comment: This question is about getting the real IP and IPv6 addresses. The comment section is for clarification, not for different questions. The answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I found the answered to my question so it resolved the issue and not needing any more details for this question.

Comment: Also in essence I do no t think you goal is to answer any questions just put holes in and find details that are not relevant to cause issues for people actually trying to get help

Comment: You solved your personal problem, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for future users with similar problem. You asked a question and gave a solution for a different problem. That won't help others.

Answer (score -1):

My issues were that I need to get an IP to use Geolocation however I was able to just go directly to Location using the below test page (this will be incorporated in to a large page and most likely streamlines but can see the process.
Thank you for all your help and questions.

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```